# Import keyword is running referenced script

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I'm trying to use the import keyword to use a variable from another python script. The problem is that each time I run script_two, it also runs script_one. I only want to run script two. Why is it doing this?

script_two.py:

```
from script_one import number

print(number)
```

script_one.py:

```
number = 1

print(number + 1)
```

Comment: importing runs the file, how else would it know what stuff does? you can't change that behaviour, you can, however, use `if __name__ == '__main__':` to limit what is executed when importing and when not importing

Comment: That's what an import does. Voting to close as it's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: Because in your `script_two`, *you* run the other one when you do `from script_one import number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the print statements in `script_one.py` to the [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) block:

`script_one.py`:

```
number = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(number + 1)
```

`script_two.py`:

```
from script_one import number

print(number)
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

To import the member variables and methods from one module/file to another, it is advised to use methods.

**References:**

- [`__main__` documentation from Python website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)